# Is there an analytic solution to this set of cubic equations?

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, cubics

I have three parameters $(a,b,c)$ that define equations I am looking for an analytical solution.

$$q_1=b/c$$
$$q_2=\frac{(a+b)^3}{3c^2b}$$
$$q_3=\frac{(a+b)^3}{3b^3}$$

I want to solve these equations for $a$, $b$, and $c$ in terms of $q_1$, $q_2$, and $q_3$. The first equation can easily be solved for $b=q_1c$. Inserting this into either of the two remaining is third degree of each parameter.

$$q_2=\frac{a^3}{3c^3q_1}+\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{aq_1}{c}+\frac{q_1^2}{3}$$
$$q_3=\frac{a^3}{27c^3q_1^3}+\frac{a^2}{9c^2q_1^2}+\frac{a}{cq_1}+\frac{1}{3}$$

This doesn't seem like a problem where I could apply the [cubic formula](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/), unless there is no error in defining a new dummy variable $x=a/c$ first and solving for its constituents later.

If there isn't an "easy" analytical solution to find I'll linearize the last two equations, but I'm looking for something more exact.

Comment: note that $q_2c^2=q_3b^2$ (subtracting third eq from second and noting $b \ne 0$ as given) so we must have $q_1^2q_3=q_2$ to have solutions

Comment: I didn't think of that, thanks. $a$, $b$ and $c$ are each non-zero.

Comment: Are they all positive as well?

Comment: Yes they are all positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly rewriting the equations to avoid fractions:

$$q_1 c = b \tag{1}$$
$$3 q_2 bc^2 = (a + b)^3 \tag{2}$$
$$3 q_3 b^3 = (a + b)^3 \tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3), we get $3 q_2 bc^2 = 3 q_3 b^3$, or $q_2 c^2 = q_3 b^2$.  But from (1), $b = q_1 c$, so plugging that in gives $q_2c^2 = q_3 q_1^2 c^2$, or $q_2 = q_1^2 q_3$.  So we don't have three independent $q$'s.  I'll deal with this redundancy later.

Taking the cube root of (3) gives:

$$b\sqrt[3]{3q_3} = a + b$$

Or equivalently, $a = (\sqrt[3]{3q_3} - 1)b$.

From (1), we get $c = \frac{b}{q_1}$.  And with explicit formulas for $a$ and $c$ in terms of $b$, we can now write (2) in terms of $b$ alone.

$$3 q_2 b(\frac{b}{q_1})^2 = 3q_3 b$$

Cancelling $b$ from each side gives an easily-solved quadratic, with $b = q_1 \frac{\sqrt{q_3}}{\sqrt{q_2}}$.

Thus, the solution is:

$$a = (\sqrt[3]{3q_3} - 1)q_1\frac{\sqrt{q_3}}{\sqrt{q_2}}$$
$$b = q_1 \frac{\sqrt{q_3}}{\sqrt{q_2}}$$
$$c = \frac{\sqrt{q_3}}{\sqrt{q_2}}$$

However, as noted earlier, the three $q$'s aren't independent, but related by $q_2 = q_1^2 q_3$.  So we only need *two* of these to express our solution.

If we substitute $q_1 = \frac{\sqrt{q_2}}{\sqrt{q_3}}$, then:

$$a = (\sqrt[3]{3q_3} - 1)$$
$$b = 1$$
$$c = \frac{\sqrt{q_3}}{\sqrt{q_2}}$$

If we substitute $q_2 = q_1^2 q_3$, then:

$$a = (\sqrt[3]{3q_3} - 1)$$
$$b = 1$$
$$c = \frac{1}{q_1}$$

Finally, if we substitute $q_3 = \frac{q_2}{q_1^2}$,

$$a = (\sqrt[3]{3\frac{q_2}{q_1^2}} - 1)$$
$$b = 1$$
$$c = \frac{1}{q_1}$$

So $b$ isn't really a variable at all!